# who programs attack speed in a game

Tags: game-design

Is it the game designer that programs attack speed and attack values for the player in a game, or does the artificial intelligence programmer program attack speed and attack values for the player in a game.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of attacks and varying speeds would be implemented by a gameplay or engine programmer typically. The designer would be the one deciding if those concepts should exist and also on the particular values of each attack.